# How to find the tower location in android

Tags: android, location, gsm

I need to find the address of the tower under which the android phone is located. I don't need to find the latitude or longitude or Location Area Code but I need the **Address**. Please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do that, you need a DB of GSM tower ids and their coordinates. Using the coordinate you can get the addresses. Probably this helps [Getting Tower GSM location lat lng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560870/getting-tower-gsm-location-lat-lng)

Comment: I don't think NOKIA 1100 and other such monochrome phones included countrywide database of GSM Tower ids and corresponding addresses! They still show up the location of the tower the phone is registered to right in the home screen!